# .htaccess redirection with only parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I am using the following url to access my category page.

> `http://example.com/category/category1`

where I am redirecting to the page `product-categories.php` and get the parameter `category1`.

Same way `http://example.com/product/product1`  for displaying products.

It is working fine.
But now my client needs the urls like,

```
http://example.com/category1
```

for category page and,

```
http://example.com/category1/product1
```

I dont have any idea to do this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Show your current rewrite rules

Comment: RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ product-categories.php?cat=$1 [L]

Comment: And all categories have format `category+some numeric id`?

Comment: no it will be just names willnot have any format

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood what you want but you can try this, in your htaccess file add this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^c_
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ product-categories.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^c_
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product-categories?category=$1&product=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Your categories should start with *c_* in this case (you can change it as you want). Thats all what i can help for now. Hope that you already solved it.

Comment: but my other pages like product-compare.php are going to product-categories.php . Can I restrict that by checking '.' in url?

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. It requests a specific url in this case category